# Converting from google maps to open street maps (osmdroid)

Tags: android, osmdroid

I built my application using Google Maps and it is using:

-BalloonItemizedOverlay

-BalloonOverlayView

-ItemizedOverlay

and what it does:

-Displays multiple points on map, each one clickable and balloon appears with relative text + description.

-Displays and updates the marker/point of user's position.

The only reason I want to switch to Open Street Map is because I would like to use the feature "caching map tiles" (presaving maps) which as far as I have looked it up is not allowed with Google Maps.

Can someone help me convert my application thoroughly to use OSMdroid instead of GoogleMaps? Providing me with some guides (very few support for OSMdroid at the moment...)

I have already looked up a lot of codes but they mostly differ in comparison with Google Maps and I can't seem to get it all right. I have managed to display user's location on the map but adding BalloonItemizedOverlays and so on is a hassle.

Anyway just help me out in any way you can - proposals on how to do it, sites with guides, anything :)

Thanks

Comment: have you made the switch yet?

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1

http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_2

I think these two tutorials should get you started with Balloons and Customized Balloons

Itemized overlay with osmdroid is quite easy to use, you should give it a try and you will get the feel of it once you try it our.